# Calculating Time and Space Complexity of xrange(), random.randint() and sort() function

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the time and space complexity of `xrange()`,`random.randint(1,100)` and `sort()` function in Python

```
import random
a = [random.randint(1,100)  for i in xrange(1000000)]
print a 
a.sort()
print a
```

Comment: yes i did..I am having problem on second line....I am not sure how much time it will be executed as it has a random function and a loop together.

Comment: Since there is no input variable, the complexity is O(1).

Comment: Thank You @StefanPochmann. If you could just elaborate a little more or any reference would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on Facebook. Thanks to Shashank Gupta.

I'm assuming you know the basics of asymptotic notation and stuff.

Now, forget the a.sort() function for a moment and concentrate on your list comprehension:
a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in xrange(1000000)]

1000000 is pretty big so let's reduce it to 10 for now.

a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in xrange(10)]

You're building a new list here with 10 elements. Each element is generated via the randint function. Let's assume the time complexity of this function is O(1). For 10 elements, this function will be called 10 times, right?

Now, let's generalize this. For integer 'n'
a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in xrange(n)]

You will be calling the randint function 'n' times.

All of this can also be written as:
for i in xrange(n):
a.append(randint(1, 100))

This is O(n).

Following the code, you've a simple print statement. This is O(n) again (internally, python interpreter iterates over the complete list). Now comes the sorting part. You've used the sort function. How much time does it take? There are many sorting algorithms out there, and without going into the exact algo used, I can safely assume the time complexity will be O(n log n)

Hence, the actual time complexity of your code is T(n) = O(n log n) + O(n) which is O(n log n) (the lower term is ignored for large n)

What about space? Your code initialized a new list of size 'n'. Hence space complexity is O(n).

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information on the problem, your actual task and your solving attempts an answer could merely be adequate...but I will try to at least give you some input.

`a = [random.randint(1,100)  for i in xrange(1000000)]`

A statement like `a = ...` is normally considered to have O(1) in terms of time complexity. Space complexity depends on how detailed you wish to analyze the problem. Simplified one might say 1.000.000 random ints in a list is something like O(1.000.000) and therefore constant, hence one could say in dependency of the input length (1.000.000, 2.000.000, ...) it results in O(n).

`[random.randint(1,100)  for i in xrange(1000000)]` is a for-loop with 1.000.000 loops and generating a random integer. In dependency of the randint-algorithm this would also be something like O(n).

`a.sort()` is highly dependent on the used sorting algorithm. Most languages use merge-sort, which is O(n * log(n)) at all cases.